# Connecting to a Synology Media Server database

Tags: postgresql

Synology NAS's provide a multimedia server backed by a PostgreSQL database. You can connect to that database from an SSH session:

```bash
sudo su -
su - postgres
psql mediaserver postgres
```

Now, I'd love to be able to connect to the database from any computer on my home network, e.g. using pgAdmin, rather than through an SSH terminal. My NAS is not exposed to the Internet and is behind my router's firewall, so I only need to open this to computers on my home network.

Can anyone guide me on how to get there? I have no knowledge whatsoever on PostgreSQL, as I'm more experienced with MySQL.

Comment: pgadmin can also ssh, so you need also to consult the manual

Comment: In the end, when I understand the connection and the schema structure, I'll want to connect through other means, but still from a computer on my home network.

Comment: if you can use for example with putty via ssh you can tunnel all traffic through the ssh tunnel.So  it doesn't matter if you use putty or ogadmin to connect it first establish a connection ia ssh and through that access the server like it was on your computer

Comment: you need to enable remote connections in [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and you also need to provide a password for the user used by your mediaserver. I **strongly** recommend to not enable remote logins for the superuser `postgres` - and if your software uses that, that is a huge security risk. You might also need to configure the firewall to let the connection through.

Comment: I'm using an SSH connection to a shell to administer the NAS, but I don't know if it would work for the postgreSQL instance that supports the media server. I have no idea what port it uses or what user would authenticate...